# Converting a Vector of Objects to array of Strings

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert a `Vector` of `Objects` that have a `toString()` method using

`(String[]) mObjectVector.toArray(new String[mObjectVector.size()])`

or

`(String[]) mObjectVector.toArray(new Object[mObjectVector.size()])`

However, it gives me the following errors:

`java.lang.ArrayStoreException: source[0] of type .../myObjectType; cannot be stored in destination array of type [Ljava/lang/String;`

and

`java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object;`

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot cast an object into the return type of that objects `toString` method. You have to build a new array by iterating over the `Vector` objects while calling `toString`.

```
String[] stringArray = new String[mObjectVector.size()];
for (int i=0; i < mObjectVector.size(); i++) {
   stringArray[i] = mObjectVector.get(i).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you cant do toArray here because your vector has custom object.

you need to manually loop the vector and call toString() on object and set it to string array.